# Why different size columns of datagridview after reload

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have method load which has following code

```
DataTable dt = db.pg_get("o_order");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;

dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

[image]

after reload this method one's more time it shows correctly like this

[image]

how to resize of datagridview column in first attempt of loading load method????

Comment: Try this dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells

Comment: this code is working but I can't fill form with datagridview how I can do it?

Comment: Try this dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

Comment: It doesn't work. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For needed column you should write down following code I think

```
dataGridView1.Columns[x].AutoSizeMode =DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```

where x needed column numbers

Comment: this code is working but I can't fill form with datagridview how I can do it?

Comment: Try this code        dataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells; T

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, `DataTable dt` is populated from database. If so try this:

```
DataTable dt = db.pg_get("o_order").ToList();
```

After reload table uses cached result